2-dimensional complete statistic
Suppose it is given that the statistics $U(\mathbf X)$ and $V(\mathbf X)$ are independent, and furthermore the family of distributions of $U(\mathbf X)$ and $V(\mathbf X)$ are complete. Does it follow that $(U(\mathbf X),V(\mathbf X))$ is complete?
Are the following steps correct for above assertion:
Suppose, joint pdf of $U,V is f_{uv}$ and $f_u, f_v $ ar the marginal distributions of $U$ and $V$ respectively, $$E(g(u,v))=0$$
$$\implies \int\int g(u,v)f_{uv}dudv =0$$
$$\implies \int(\int g(u,v)f_udu)f_vdv =0$$
$$\implies \int h(v)f_vdv =0$$
$\implies h(v)=0, a.e $   since $V(\mathbf X)$  is complete.
$$\implies \int g(u,v)f_u =0$$
$$\implies g(u,v) =0, a.e$$ Hence, the result follows as $U(\mathbf X)$ is complete?

Looks perfectly correct for me.
